# Visual Studio 2013 VSTO not creating Word 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-addins, word-2010

I'm trying to develop a Word Document add-in through Visual Studio 2013, using a Word 2010 Document selected from the Visual Studio project menu of Office/SharePoint Office Add-ins.  It is needed to tie in SharePoint 2013 with a collaborative Word document.  I keep getting the error message:

Project cannot be created because the "Word Visual Studio Design-Time Adaptor Add-in" is not working correctly. Word might have disabled the add-in or made it inactive, or all add-ins might be disabled in your Trust Center settings.  Check the add-in status in Word Options.  If the add-in is active and enabled, reinstall or repair Visual Studio Tools for Office.

I have checked that there is no disabled add-ins in the Trust Center, and I do see the Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime in the Add-ins.  I cannot find any other options, as I have reinstalled the Visual Studio Tools for Office as well.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turned out that one of the updates was causing the problem. (Breaking the VSTO plug-in in some way)

What I did was reinstall Office, and I manually told Microsoft Update not to install updates that were launched after Oct 2016, I could then create Document-Level projects again.

Comment: Thanks Shadowfox.  I'm not sure that's exactly the problem anymore.  It has to do with some security settings on our network by the IT department.